# Excel Ranking tie assistance

Tags: excel, ranking

Can anyone help me to do the following in relation to ties when using the Excel Rank function?

Col A contains scores and B contains the rank. I am quite happy with this except that I would like to show an '=' next to the ranking where it is a tie:

```
Score   Rank
66  3
64  4= 
63  6 
68  2
64  4=  
81  1
```

etc

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check here on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your `RANK` with `COUNITF`. Place the following into cell **B3** as per the example

```
=RANK(A3,$A$3:$A$7)&IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7,A3)>1,"=","")
```

[image]

*Note, if you are using Excel 2013 or 2016, it would be a good idea to replace `RANK` with `RANK.EQ`*

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Many thanks for making my first visit to SO useful.

Comment: Hi @JimMills, always happy to help! If you find that answered your question please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in another column next to the column where you have ranked it.

**Step 1:** Rank the numbers in a simple manner using `RANK.EQ`

*Output:*

```
(A)|(B)
66 | 3
64 | 4
63 | 6
68 | 2
64 | 4
81 | 1
```

**Step 2:** In another column use the code `IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,CONCATENATE(B1,"="), B1)`

*Output:*

```
(A)|(B)|(C)
66 | 3 | 3
64 | 4 | 4=
63 | 6 | 6
68 | 2 | 2
64 | 4 | 4=
81 | 1 | 1
```

You can paste the values and remove the columns as required.

Hope it helps. :)